# tomcat gives 404 after successful war deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Problem:
I am relatively new to tomcat, i deployed a war file from the new project i am working on and it deploys fine without any problems, but when i try to run the app it gives 404. 
I tried :
tried to find the appropriate error messages but,no errors seen in eclipse console nor in logs folder in tomcat installation directory. How do i troubleshoot this problem? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add your web app to tomcat? Servers tab -> Right click on server name -> Add and Remove... I'm mentioning that because from what I understood you deployed it in elipcse

Comment: More details code also what does your website look like

Comment: can you update your post with deployment descriptor and page url you are trying to access?

Comment: i did deploy it by doing add or remove functionality in eclipse.

Comment: add an index.html page, if you don't have one

Comment: thank you all, i figured it out. It was running fine when i manually deployed on tomcat console. As far as deployment through eclipse is concerned i fixed it by enabling maven nature on the project.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Please check this file:** ( sometimes the console won't give any tips)

```
${tomcat-root-directory}/logs/localhost.yyyy-MM-dd.log
```

**2. My case:**
    I depolyed war file **successfully** logging from the console's output. 
    But when I access the url in browser, I get **404 error**.

I checked the log, found that java source files are missing. and there was a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.
Then I remembered that I use the `maven clean` command, before packaging the war file.  It deleted them! Without those resource files, my war project doesn't start up properly. and I checked `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html` tomcat webapps management page, my war project running status is false.